# Is there a way where I can attach to an existing browser context, and interact with a page within that context using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a Windows application, while clicking on a certain element it will open a tab in a browser and I'll need to interact with that already opened browser tab and do some web automation using Python.

Selenium is not working in this case since it always starts the driver in a new browser instance.

Comment: Thank you.
I need to switch to the browser session which is not created by Selenium but it is opened manually